# Error connecting to HTTP server using web3 and hosting the website

Tags: pythonanywhere, web3py

I was attempting to connect to a projects http server using web3 and host my website to display the list of users with the most eth in their account. This works when I created a local flask webpage; however, for the project, I want to display it for everyone so I was attempting to host it on pythonanywhere. However, whenever I do this, I get the following error:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url

Everything works fine when I run it locally but running it off pythonanywhere gives me these errors.

I was wondering how I would fix this. Let me know if more code needs to be displayed.

Comment: please include in your question:
- what are the exact steps you are doing to reproduce the error
- if your web-app is firing the exception, try to get a minimum code that still have this problem and share it here. 

If I understand correctly, pythonanywhere free tier does not allow you to send outbound requests from your application, so that might be the reason.

Comment: It could be related to limited internet access of free accounts on PythonAnywhere, but it's hard to say with limited information presented here.